# Windows Phone 7 Local Database Access Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

Here my code:

```
if (!appdb.DatabaseExists())
{
    appdb.CreateDatabase();
}

var income = from p in appdb.Incomes select p.Amount;
var expense = from q in appdb.Expenses select q.eAmount;

double di = 0;
if (income != null)
{
    foreach (var i in income)
    {
        di += i;
    }
}

double de = 0;
if (expense != null)
{
    foreach (var d in expense)
    {
        de += d;
    }
}
```

There are two table in appdb (Income and Expense) both are having same columns. I am able to insert and retrieve data from Income table but am getting error at `foreach(var d in expense)`. The error message is "The specified table does not exist. [ Expenses ]" and errorcode is "-2147467259". Please! can any one explain why I am getting this error.

Comment: I found something similar here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/20/sqlceexception-the-specified-table-does-not-exist-tablenamehere.aspx. Maybe this will help.

Comment: You're going to have to include at least the `Incomes` and `Expenses` properties from your datacontext type to help here.